# Javascript, withoutString

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

I am writing a function in JavaScript that takes 2 strings, the first any sentence entered by the user. The second a few letters that should be removed from the original sentence.  I am trying to take both strings, make them into arrays, then slice/splice to remove the second str from the first.

```
let sentencePrompt = prompt("Please enter any sentence: ");
let removePrompt = prompt("Please enter a string of letter(s) to be removed from your original sentence: ");
function withoutString(sentence, str)
{
    let sentenceArray = sentence.split("");
    let removeArray = str.split("");
    let sentenceLength = sentenceArray.length;
    let removeLength = strArray.length - 1;
    for(let i = 0; i < sentenceLength; i++)
    {
        if((sentenceArray.slice(i, i+removeLength)) === removeArray)
        {
            sentenceArray = sentenceArray.splice(i, i+removeLength);
        }
    }
    return sentenceArray;
}
let newSentence = withoutString(sentencePrompt, removePrompt);
console.log(sentencePrompt);
console.log(removePrompt);
console.log(newSentence);
```

this just outputs the original sentence, without removing anything. any advice? thanks.

Comment: I would look into .replace() with regular expression.

Comment: let removeLength = strArray.length -1;
should be 
let removeLength = removeArray.length-1;

Comment: Just to let you know: you can [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags. Avoid adding corrections/extra info in the comments, as comments are harder to read and can be deleted easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to do what you want with replace function

```
let sentencePrompt = prompt("Please enter any sentence: ");
let removePrompt = prompt("Please enter a string of letter(s) to be removed from your original sentence: ");

let newSentence = sentencePrompt.replace(removePrompt, '');

alert(newSentence);
```

Here is a working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/so7ycn05/).